# grails customize the fields and the order they will appear in scaffolding generate index view

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I want to customize the fields and the order they will appear in scaffolding generated index view.

My idea is to create a static field called indexFields that is a map of the fields I want to display at generated index.gsp.

At the scaffolding template there is a class called domainClass.persistentProperties.

How do I read a static property at a domain class?

Comment: Or you could just change the order of your constraints, since that's the order in which they are displayed in the scaffolding pages.

Comment: I've tried that but I doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution

At the domain
static indexList = ['number', 'carrier', 'validThrough', 'inUse', 'dateUsed', 'active']

read it at the index.gsp (scaffolding template)

```
 def listFields = domainClass.getClazz()['indexList']


  if(listFields){
    allowedNames=listFields
    props = []
    listFields.each{p ->
        props<<domainClass.getPropertyByName(p)
    }
}else{
    props = domainClass.properties.findAll {   ...}
    Collections.sort(props, comparator.constructors[0].newInstance([domainClass] as Object[]))
}
```